# Asynchronous HTTP request causes cross-threading exception

Tags: .net, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fixing a Cross-Thread Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919725/fixing-a-cross-thread-exception)

I'm using asynchronous HTTP requests to send a web request and obtain the response without blocking the UI. This works fine until I try and place the response into a label on a form at which point I get a "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on". I am aware of the issues with accessing controls from different threads, and the use of delegates to get around it.

I suspect what is happening is the web callback code is executing on a different thread, therefore it can't access the controls which were created on the original thread, but I guess I don't fully understand how the callback uses additional threads in the first place.

What I want is to be able to issue a web request, get on with other business, then obtain the response later when it arrives, and be able to place the responses on controls

```
Public Sub Test()
    SendAsynchRequest("http://google.com")
End Sub

Public Sub SendAsynchRequest(ByVal MyURL As String, Optional ByVal Timeout As Integer = 30)
    'send an asynch web request

    Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Dim result As IAsyncResult
    Dim state As WebRequestState
    Dim reqtimeout As Integer

    Try
        request = CType(WebRequest.Create(MyURL), HttpWebRequest)   ' Create the request
        request.Proxy = Nothing

        state = New WebRequestState(request)        ' Create the state object used to access the web request
        result = request.BeginGetResponse(New AsyncCallback(AddressOf RequestComplete), state)
        reqtimeout = 1000 * Timeout
        ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(result.AsyncWaitHandle, New WaitOrTimerCallback(AddressOf TimeoutCallback), state, reqtimeout, True)

    Catch ex As Exception
        log.Error("Error sending web request: " & ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub TimeoutCallback(ByVal state As Object, ByVal timeOut As Boolean)
    'request times out    
    If (timeOut) Then
        ' Abort the request
        CType(state, WebRequestState).Request.Abort()
        Dim orig_url = CType(state, WebRequestState).Request
        log.Error("Web request to: " & orig_url.RequestUri.ToString & " timed out")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RequestComplete(ByVal result As IAsyncResult)
    'called when the request completes

    Dim request As WebRequest
    Dim response As System.IO.Stream
    Dim sr As StreamReader

    Try
        request = DirectCast(result.AsyncState, WebRequestState).Request
        response = request.EndGetResponse(result).GetResponseStream
        sr = New StreamReader(response)
        log.Info("Received Web response: " & sr.ReadToEnd)

        '*********************************************************
        ' THIS LINE CAUSES A CROSS-THREAD ERROR
        '*********************************************************
        TextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd

    Catch ex As Exception
        log.Error("Received error code: " & ex.Message)

    End Try

End Sub

Private Class WebRequestState
    'Stores web request for access during async processing
    Public Request As WebRequest

    Public Sub New(ByVal newRequest As WebRequest)
        Request = newRequest
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: That's true for all asynchronous operations, not only http requests, and - right, you should have searched for exception text before asking, really

Comment: What wasn't clear to me is where and how the new thread is being created. And I searched all over before asking. There are plenty of threads about cross-thread exceptions, but I could not find anything about async operations causing them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure this has been answered many times before.
You need to use the Control.Invoke function to run the update on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

At the line of the error, replace with the following:

```
TextBox1.Invoke(Sub()
                   TextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd
                End Sub)
```